# Smart card reader not working in Manjaro 19

Tags: drivers, smartcard

I am running Manjaro 19.0.2, and I am struggling to get it to even detect a smart card reader I'm using: the [SCR3310v2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002N3MM6W). I need this to work in order to access online US Military resources using a [CAC](https://www.cac.mil/) to verify and authenticate my identity. I am using Firefox 75.0 as my browser of choice.

I have already followed all the steps laid out in the [DoD Cyber Exchange guide to using CAC for Firefox in Linux](https://public.cyber.mil/pki-pke/end-users/getting-started/#toggle-id-3). I have also followed [MilitaryCAC's guide for Linux users](https://militarycac.com/linux.htm).

The following is a summary of the two guides linked above.

For PKCS#11 implementation, I am using [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki). I have also installed the four packages prescribed by [MilitaryCAC](https://militarycac.com/linux.htm):

> **[pcsc-lite](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/)** - PCSC Smart Cards Library
>     **pcsc-ccid*** - generic USB CCID (Chip/Smart Card Interface Devices) driver
>     **[perl-pcsc](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-perl/)** - Abstraction layer to smart card readers
>     **[pcsc-tools](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/)** - Optional but highly recommended, these tools are used to test a PCSC driver, card and reader

**exact package name not found in pamac manager; installed [ccid](https://ccid.apdu.fr/) instead*

I imported to Firefox all credentials located in https://militarycac.com/maccerts/AllCerts.zip (link provided by MilitaryCAC). I loaded a file called `opensc-pkcs11.so` in Firefox security settings.

After doing all of this work, the smart card reader will not even light up upon connecting it to my PC, which is typical in Windows machines. There is no indication of the hardware being detected in the file explorer, either.

I know there's nothing wrong with the reader itself, as it works just fine in a Windows. I also know it's not because of missing USB drivers, as they are installed with Manjaro from the get-go, or their faulty configurations, as my PC is able to detect and interface with other USB connected hardware, such as my phone.

I am clueless as to what I could try next, save for running Windows in a virtual machine. I would much prefer to have it work in Linux, if possible. Any help is welcome and greatly appreciated.

---

### NOTE

I managed to solve this problem. The solution that worked for me is found below. Also note that since this question was posted, my distro version was updated to v20.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. Here's how I did it.

1. Using your package manager (in my case, `pamac`), install the
   following packages, as detailed in my original post:

   - [pcsc-perl](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-perl/)
   - [pcsc-tools](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/)
   - [pcsclite](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/)
   - [ccid](https://ccid.apdu.fr/)
   - [opensc](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki)
2. Download DoD certificates from [this location](https://militarycac.com/maccerts/AllCerts.zip) and extract them.
3. From Firefox, go to Edit > Preferences > Privacy & Security > Certificates > View Certificates > Authorities > Import
4. Find and import the extracted certificates
5. Click on **DoD Root CA 2**, then **Edit Trust** and make sure both options are checked*. Once this is done, press OK
6. Click on **Security Devices**, and then **Load**. Find and open the file `opensc-pkcs11.so`. Mine was located in `/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so`
7. Open the terminal and run `pgrep -l pcscd`. As telcoM suggested, you should see an output. If you get nothing, run the two commands in his/her comment to start the `pcscd` service now and have it run on bootup. `pgrep -l pcscd` should now output a number followed by `pcscd`
8. Restart machine
9. Open terminal and run `pcsc_scan`. The last line in the output should read `Waiting for the first reader...`
10. Plug in your smart card reader. It should immediately detect it. The terminal should now say `Card removed` and `Card inserted` for every time you insert or remove your card, along with all kinds of details regarding the card.
11. You should now be able to access content online requiring authentication with the smart card and its reader.

*I don't know if this is strictly necessary, but that's how mine is set up.

The sources used are:

- [MilitaryCAC for Linux Users](https://militarycac.com/linux.htm)
- [Arch Linux's wiki guide for smart cards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Smartcards)
- telcoM's comment response to this post

Comment: Just a note. The software stack/"chain of things" in between the card and Firefox goes like this: card -> reader -> ccid driver -> `pcscd` -> `opensc-pkcs11.so` in Firefox -> the rest of Firefox. The `pcsc_scan` tests `pcscd` directly, so you could move the steps 7..10 in your procedure up before step 2 for a logical progression, but the way you have it now also works.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `pcscd` process running? (Does `pgrep -l pcscd` output anything?) It should run as a service/daemon, but you might need to enable it first.

```
sudo systemctl start pcscd.service     # start it now
sudo systemctl enable pcscd.service    # make it start automatically at boot in the future too
```

The `pcsc_scan` command should then detect your card reader and give some technical information of your card when inserted.

See also this chain of posts on the Manjaro forum:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-smartcard-reader-not-shown/39460

Basically, poster kubwit's card reader used a custom USB product/vendor ID that needed to be added to `/etc/libccid_Info.plist` before the `ccid` driver detected the card. Your card reader *should* be supported as-is, unless the vendor ID has recently changed (as that card reader is originally from SCR product line, but Identiv bought SCR some time ago).

Comment: Hello! `pgrep -l pcscd` did not output anything at first. I then typed the commands you instructed and restarted my system with no issues. It now says `1707 pcscd`. However, my card reader still does not light up upon connection.

I checked the thread you linked in the Manjaro forum. It appears that kubwit's solution was to simply install `ccid` and restart his/her machine, which I have also done.

I am willing to try to add the product and vendor ID to `/etc/libccid_Info.plist` but this was not elaborated on. I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: One thing I noticed that is different now is that under Firefox preferences > Privacy & Security > Security Devices, the module I previously loaded (`opensc-pkcs11.so`) now has an entry under it with a description that reads `SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR 3310 [CCID...]` (The rest of the description is cut off). Its status is `Not Present`, and this is while I have the smart card reader plugged in with a card (CAC) in it. This entry was not there before.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a bit of an issue on Manjaro, as well. `pcsc_scan` (after installing everything Manuel listed) was showing that the card is detected correctly, but I could not manage to setup Firefox successfully with the Security device `/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so`. When I did so, Firefox would start to freeze up and would not allow me to sign into the module.

From my national eID provider I got a .deb file for download. This file contains the certificates, some executables and the eponymous `libEidPkcs11.so`.

Once extracted on my filesystem, this .so file could be loaded into Firefox and Firefox allowed me to login with my Identification pin. Also the provided executable files appear to be working correctly on Manjaro.

Finally, I had another minor foible in Libre Office Writer, which was basically my lack of understanding. It turns out that Writer will show current document digital signatures on the digital signatures list and your digital signature options will only show up when you press the `Sign document...` button. This was a bit counter intuitive for me, but is now straightened out.